# Let $f \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ be irreducible, $\deg(f)=n$. Then: $|Gal(f)|=n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

This is a task from an old exam I'm doing as an exercise:

---

Are the following true or false?

1. $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}\ [\mathbb{Q}(\exp(2\pi i / n) : \mathbb{Q}] = n-1$.
2. Let $f \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ be irreducible, $\deg(f)=n$. Then $|Gal(f)|=n$.
3. Let $K(a)/K$ be an algebraic field extension. Then $Gal(K(a)/K)$ is commutative.
4. Let $L/K$ be a finite field extension and $|Gal(L/K)|=1$. Then $L/K$ is normal.

---

My solution:

1. is true because $\exp(2\pi i /n)$ is a primitive identity root, hence it creates all $n$ roots. So the minimal polynomial must have degree $n$ (since $\mathbb{Q}$ is perfect the field extension is separable, so there are no multiple roots).
2. is false, we have proven in our lectures that $|Gal(f)| \leq \deg(f)!$

Is this correct?

And how can I solve 3) and 4)?

Answer (score 3):

**Hints.**

1. Try with $n=4$.
2. Try with $f=X^3-2\in\mathbb{Q}[X]$
3. Set $K=\mathbb{Q}$, and take $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}+j), $ where $ j$ is a primitive 3rd root of $1$.
4. Set $K=\mathbb{Q}$, and take $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$.

Comment: 1) is clear now. But I'm still struggling with the others sorry. Do I understand the 2) correct this way? $x^3-2=0 \Rightarrow x=\sqrt[3]{2}$ or two other solutions which are complex and not real numbers. Thus, if you take $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ it is already a field extension of degree $3$, but the other complex solutions aren't in it. So if you add these as well you get a field extension of a higher degree. Therefore 2) is wrong. Is this correct now?

Comment: For 3. you meant $L=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}+e^{2i\pi/3})$

Comment: @reuns: yes, of course, thanks. Edited.

Comment: @LuTo: Yes, 2) is correct , now. For 4., compute the embeddings into $\mathbb{C}$, and just see that the only automorphism is the identity (note that $L$ is a subfield of the reals...)

Comment: @Luto. For 3. Prove that $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2},j)$ and prove the Galois group is not abelian. OR, as an alternative approach: pick your favorite Galois extension $L/K$ with non abelian galois group, then pick a primitive element $a\in L$, so that $L=K(a)$...